# How can I use multiple parameters using pandas pd.read_sql_query?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass three variables in a sql query. These are region, feature, newUser. I am using SQL driver SQL Server Native Client 11.0.

Here is my code  that works.

```
query = "SELECT LicenseNo FROM License_Mgmt_Reporting.dbo.MATLAB_NNU_OPTIONS  WHERE Region = ?"

data_df = pd.read_sql_query((query),engine,params={region})
```

output.

```
     LicenseNo
 0           12
 1            5
```

Instead i want to pass in three variables and this code does not work.

```
query = "SELECT LicenseNo FROM License_Mgmt_Reporting.dbo.MATLAB_NNU_OPTIONS WHERE Region = ? and FeatureName = ? and NewUser =?"

nnu_data_df = pd.read_sql_query((query),engine,params={region, feature, newUser})
```

Output returns an empty data frame.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [LicenseNo]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try a string in a tuple, also you can take out the () in the query:

so you could do something like

```
query = "SELECT LicenseNo FROM License_Mgmt_Reporting.dbo.MATLAB_NNU_OPTIONS WHERE Region = ? and FeatureName = ? and NewUser =?"
region = 'US'
feature = 'tall'
newUser = 'john'
data_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params=(region, feature , newUser))
```

Comment: Hi Steven - I converted region, feature, and newUser to strings and used your syntax and still returned an empty data frame.

Comment: query = "SELECT LicenseNo FROM License_Mgmt_Reporting.dbo.MATLAB_NNU_OPTIONS WHERE Region = ? and FeatureName = ? and NewUser =?"

            Region = str(region)
            FeatureName = str(feature)
            NewUser = str(newUser)

            nnu_data_df = pd.read_sql_query(query,engine, params=(Region, FeatureName, NewUser))

Comment: sorry Steven I forgot to tag you

Comment: Can this work even with snowflake sql? even after setting `snowflake.connector.paramstyle='qmark'` its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Operator error by me :( I was using the wrong variable and the database returned no results because it didn't exist!