# How to use two variables in one SQL statement?

Tags: python, sql

I've got a problem regarding SQL and Python.

In my code I'm trying to search for two elements using a entry field. It's either the `CommercialCode` or the `ItemNumber`. This code for the `ItemNumber` works perfectly fine (just the last part is important):

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query("Select top 1 UnitWeight, GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber, GlobalItemDescription.Description,  GlobalItemMaster_new.CommodityCode, CommercialCode, GlobalItemMaster_new.DRICode  from dbo.GlobalItemDescription inner join dbo.GlobalItemMaster_new on GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber = GlobalItemMaster_new.ItemNumber where dbo.GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber like '%s'" % eingabe, conn)
```

But actually I want it like this:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query("Select top 1 UnitWeight, GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber, GlobalItemDescription.Description,  GlobalItemMaster_new.CommodityCode, CommercialCode, GlobalItemMaster_new.DRICode  from dbo.GlobalItemDescription inner join dbo.GlobalItemMaster_new on GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber = GlobalItemMaster_new.ItemNumber where dbo.GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber like '%s' OR dbo.GlobalItemMaster_new.CommercialCode like '%s'" % eingabe, eingabe2,conn)
```

When I execute the code above I get this error:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Consider using parameterized queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use multiple parameters using pandas pd.read\_sql\_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180884/how-can-i-use-multiple-parameters-using-pandas-pd-read-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `paranthesis`, so it should be `% (eingabe, eingabe2)` instead of `% eingabe, eingabe2`

```
 SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query("Select top 1 UnitWeight, GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber, GlobalItemDescription.Description,  GlobalItemMaster_new.CommodityCode, CommercialCode, GlobalItemMaster_new.DRICode  from dbo.GlobalItemDescription inner join dbo.GlobalItemMaster_new on GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber = GlobalItemMaster_new.ItemNumber where dbo.GlobalItemDescription.ItemNumber like '%s' OR dbo.GlobalItemMaster_new.CommercialCode like '%s'" % (eingabe, eingabe2),conn)
```

Comment: This answer provides security issues allowing SQL Injections.

Comment: But this answer answers the question of OP. The question is about "How to use two variables in one SQL statement" and the error was "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Comment: I dont know why, but my programm freezes with this solution